# cordova net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Tags: cordova

i have an cordova pp 
i am calling a post method in controller 
it works in browser , but in build and debug apk i get the error

ionic.bundle.js:23826 POST http://somedomain.com/api/account/validation net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

my angular controller

```
.controller('splashCtrl', function ($scope, $state,$http, userManager, serverConfig) {
    //check if the user exist else it will redirect to login 
    $scope.authenticate = function () {

        $http.post(serverConfig.serverUrl + '/api/account/validation').success(function (res,status) {

            if (status == '200') {

                //check if the user need to change password
                if (window.localStorage.getItem('shouldChangePassword') && window.localStorage.getItem('shouldChangePassword')=='true') {
                    $state.go('setPassword');
                    return;
                }

                $state.go('tab.category');
            }

        }).error(function (data, status) {
            console.log(status)
        })


    }

    $scope.authenticate();


})
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: have you added the permission in manifest file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This Error means you don't have access to internet.There are two ways you can provide this access by changing these files

**1.AndroidManifest.xml**

add these following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK_ACCESS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**2. config.xml**

For this you are going to need this plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config
```

after adding this plugin , add these lines in you config.xml

```
<platform name="android">
   <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.NETWORK_ACCESS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   </config-file>
</platform>
```

You can try it . Hope it helps you .Thanks

Comment: i havent test this , but a while ago it was working , i suspect a phonega-push-notofication plugin installation and removal cause this problem .

Comment: You might need to ensure the `android` namespace is declared in your `config.xml` file: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Comment: @user6599525 yes , for some reason this issue also happened to me when after removing the phonegap-push-notification.

Comment: The second solution worked once I surrounded the user-permission tags with a CDATA section

Comment: I can concur with the comment about "phonega-push-notofication plugin installation and removal". I had a project containing 2 apps where app1 used PNs and app2 didnt. So my build script would remove plugin "cordova-plugin-push" for app2 and add it for app1. This seemed to work for a while untl I started getting ERR_CACHE_MISS for app2. Solved by not removing plugin. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 8):

If you encounter this problem after removing a plugin or installing a plugin then this solution might work for you.

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

There is no harm in trying it even if you've not installed or removed any plugin.

Comment: This strangely worked for me 

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you have recently uninstalled a plugin and it started happening, then the solution by David Addoteye to remove and add the platform back may do it, worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29851865)